Error encountering upon executing CLI "gem install rails"
I'm newbie on ROR. trying to set up a local development and study.
I already have ruby dev kit which i install from rubyinstaller.org (Ruby+Devkit 3.2.3-1 (x64))
here is my ruby version -> ruby 3.2.3 (2024-01-18 revision 52bb2ac0a6) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
Now, when executing or installing "gem install rails" on CLI, i got this error:
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/My name here/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/My name here/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.2/ext/psych
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Users/My name here/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.2/mkmf.log

Now when i check the mkmf.log, here is the result:
PATH=".;C:/Ruby32-x64/lib;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Kube;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\sqlite;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Kubernetes\Minikube;C:\Program Files\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\My name here surname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\terraform;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2\bin;C:\Program Files\qpdf 11.5.0\bin;;C:\Users\My name here\AppData\Roaming\npm" "gcc -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/x64-mingw-ucrt -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong -m64  -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <yaml.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <yaml.h>
/* end */

Seeking help here, I'm currently lost

Does this answer your question? MinGW pacman -Sys Unable to lock database

no, still same issue. :(

already solved. running CMD as admin
then  type on cli ->

ridk enable
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc
gem install rails

that should work

Glad you got it fixed! This answer would be more helpful to others if you explained what the problem was, what those commands do, and how they solved the problem.
